# Multi level list with links in Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a collection with fields `groupNumber` and `number`:

```
groupNumber, number
=================
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
2, 1
2, 2
2, 3
2, 8
3, 4
3, 5
...
```

I can print the entire collection with

```
{{#each numbers}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{groupNumber}}</td>
    <td>{{number}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

but I need it to be links instead. So at the first page I need to see a list of the group numbers (1, 2, 3, ...) and when I've clicked one of the groups, I see the numbers belonging to this group.

I could easily achieve this if I had `groupNumber` and `number` split in two different collections and use `iron-router` to navigate between list of groups and list of numbers belonging to group. But how can I get this with the two fields in the same collection?

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you "group" your groups manually?

At first get all your group numbers.

```
var allValues = YourCollection.find().fetch();
var uniqueGroups = _.union(_.pluck(allValues, 'groupNumber')) //outputs [1,2,3]
```

After that, simple route will do the job:

```
Router.route('/group/:groupNumber?', function () {
  this.render('your_template', {
    data: function () {
      if(this.params.hasOwnProperty('groupNumber')){
          return {
             groupNumber: this.params.groupNumber
          }
      } else {
          var allValues = YourCollection.find().fetch();
          var uniqueGroups = _.union(_.pluck(allValues, 'groupNumber'))
          return {
              groups: uniqueGroups
          }
      }  
    }
  });
});
```

Then in `your_template` check, if you have groupNumber, show all numbers
by `YourCollection.find({groupNumber: this.groupNumber})`

if not, then just render `this.groups`:

```
{{#each groups}}
<a href="/group/{{this}}">{{this}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: What if I have two more levels `group1`, `group2`, `group3`, and `group4`?

Comment: You're really asking a UX paradigm instead of using routes.

Comment: The same logic applies with > 1 level of nesting or even recursive nesting. The only thing that seems missing from @Zuzel's answer is sorting which you presumably want to do at each level.